# How to use .bfill() with pandas groupby without dropping the grouping variable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use bfill and groupby but have not figured out a way to do so without dropping the grouping variable. I know I can just concatenate back the ID column but there's gotta be another way of doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


test = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                     'dd': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     'nu': np.array([0, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN, 10, 20])})


In [11]:test.groupby('ID').bfill()

Out[11]: 
     nu
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   NaN
3  10.0
4  10.0
5  20.0
```

Desired output

```
  ID  dd    nu
0  A   0   0.0
1  A   0   1.0
2  A   0   NaN
3  B   0  10.0
4  B   0  10.0
5  B   0  20.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
>>> test.assign(nu=test.groupby('ID').bfill()['nu'])
  ID  dd    nu
0  A   0   0.0
1  A   0   1.0
2  A   0   NaN
3  B   0  10.0
4  B   0  10.0
5  B   0  20.0
```

Or [`df.groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html),

```
>>> test.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x:x.bfill())
  ID  dd    nu
0  A   0   0.0
1  A   0   1.0
2  A   0   NaN
3  B   0  10.0
4  B   0  10.0
5  B   0  20.0
```